# How to use a proved lemma in Coq

Tags: coq

As elementary as it seems, I can't solve the following problem. There's this inductive type for even naturals and a proven lemma expressing that adding two even numbers yields an even number.

```
Inductive even : nat -> Prop :=
| O_even : even 0
| plus_2_even : forall n:nat, even n -> even (S (S n)).

Lemma lm_even1: forall n p:nat, even n -> even p -> even (n + p).
```

I'd like to prove the special case that n + 2 is even:

```
Lemma lm_even2: forall n: nat, even n -> even (n + 2).
```

The more general `lm_even1` would come handy here but I keep failing with my efforts using apply, rewrite etc. to express that `lm_even2` is the same statement with "p = 2". Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might get a better answer if you show us what you've tried (explicitly). There's a short proof with just `apply` and one or two other basic tactics, but maybe you have a misunderstanding somewhere. Fixing that misunderstanding would be more helpful for you in the long term.

---

We should start by introducing all the premises. There's a good reason for this that I'll discuss below.

```
Lemma lm_even2: forall n: nat, even n -> even (n + 2).
Proof.
  intros.
```

Now the proof state is

```
1 subgoal
n : nat
H : even n
______________________________________(1/1)
even (n + 2)
```

Now we're in a position to `apply lm_even1.`. `apply term.` attempts to unify the type of `term` with the goal, possibly filling in arguments to `term` from left to right (if it's some kind of function).

So, for example, `apply lm_even1.` would first try to unify with the full type

```
forall n p : nat, even n -> even p -> even (n + p)
```

Then it'll try with some variable to be determined as the first argument (of type `nat`):

```
forall p : nat, even ?n -> even p -> even (?n + p)
```

Then the same for `p`: `even ?n -> even ?p -> even (?n + ?p)`. Next, since this is still a function type, it can continue by filling in the argument of type `even ?n` with some unknown variable: `even ?p -> even (?n + ?p)` and finally, `even (?n + ?p)`.

The only one of those that could match the goal is the last one: `even (?n + ?p)` with `?n = n` and `?p = 2`. If we hadn't introduced the variables, this wouldn't work at all because none of the other types match the original goal.

```
Lemma lm_even2: forall n: nat, even n -> even (n + 2).
Proof.
  intros.
  apply lm_even1.
```

Now the proof state is

```
2 subgoals
n : nat
H : even n
______________________________________(1/2)
even n
______________________________________(2/2)
even 2
```

So we have two goals: `even n` and `even 2`. Both should be fairly easy to reach using the premises and the definition of `even`.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I did try 'apply lm_even1', but unfortunately without using 'intros' first.